# How many rounds of blackjack do you have to simulate to get accurate outcome probabilities?

Tags: probability

Say you play blackjack a lot and record how often each outcome occurs (win, push, lose, win $2x$, lose $2x$, $+3x$, $-3x$, $+4x$, $-4x$, $+1.5x$) (keep in mind you can double and split).

How many rounds would you have to play to be $90\%$ certain that the probabilities you record are within $0.001\%$ of the actual probabilities?

## edit

Assuming you play using the [basic strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Basic_strategy) which is consistent from round to round (no card counting).

Comment: The actual outcomes depend on a strategy (only the bank strategy is determined), e.g. you may decide to always split with two sixes and never with two tens. So one would at least need that all reasonable cases have occured sufficiently often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 90% confidence is close enough to 2SD (that actually matches better with 95% confidence, but let's forget that). For the purposes of estimating the probability of a single outcome a single round is a Bernoulli trial. Let's say that the true probability of outcome A is $p$. Let $X$ be the random variable that counts how many times outcome $A$ occurred in $N$ rounds of simulation. The expected value of $X$ is then $E(X)=Np$. The variance of $X$ is $\sigma^2=Np(1-p)$. Therefore $\pm$2SD-interval of $X$ has halfwidth
$
2\sigma=2\sqrt{Np(1-p)}.
$
When we estimate $p$ with $X/N$, the 2SD error would then be 
$$\Delta p=\frac{2\sigma}{N}=\frac{2\sqrt{p(1-p)}}{\sqrt{N}}.$$
You asked for $\Delta p<10^{-5}$, so you want
$$
\sqrt{N}>2\cdot10^5\sqrt{p(1-p)}\Longleftrightarrow N>4\cdot10^{10}p(1-p).
$$
After you have done enough many rounds of your simulation, you will have a fairly good ideas of the value of $p(1-p)$, so you can use the above formula.

This formula probably has some inaccuracies, but for large $N$ they are hopefully negligible.

You see that getting such an accurate estimate for a probability by Bernoulli trials takes a large number of them. When I was doing channel coding simulations in a previous job we used a ball park figure of requiring $X>200$ before stopping a simulation. This could be trusted to give one significant figure for $p$. We were mostly interested in $\log_{10}p$ with a margin of error something like $\pm 0.1$, so that was about right :-)

Comment: Doesn't the fact that we have $10$ outcomes and we want *all* of them to be within $10^{-5}$ make some difference?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It depends what you want. If you want to be 90% confident that estimates for **all** the probabilities are within $10^{-5}$, then sure, you need extra rounds. Otherwise I would think that once the number of rounds reaches the above bound for all the estimated $p$:s, then you should be safe. Note that $p(1-p)$ reaches its maximum at $p=1/2$, so $N>10^{10}$ rounds will be enough to get a small enough 90% confidence interval on any individual $p$.